# Header needs to slide up and down on page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a div at the top of my page with some simple contact information and social media links that I hide on down scroll and that reappears when you reach the top of the page. All I'd like is for this transition to happen more smoothly. A slide up and down would be nice but I have not been successful in getting it to work. Below is what I have right now:

```js
(function($) {
  "use strict";
function mainNavbar() {
  if ($('#main_navbar').length) {
    $('#main_navbar').affix({
      offset: {
        top: 10,
        bottom: function() {
          return (this.bottom = $('.footer').outerHeight(true))
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
mainNavbar();
})
```

```css
.top_header_area {
  background: #333333;
}

.top_header_area .top_nav li a {
  font: 400 14px/50px "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.top_header_area .top_nav li a i {
  color: #cc0033;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.top_header_area .top_nav li a:hover,
.top_header_area .top_nav li a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #cc0033;
}

.top_header_area .top_nav li:first-child a {
  padding: 0;
}

.top_header_area .social_nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 12px;
}

.top_header_area .social_nav li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.top_header_area .social_nav li a i {
  line-height: 24px;
}

.top_header_area .social_nav li a:hover,
.top_header_area .social_nav li a:focus {
  background: #cc0033;
  color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="top" class="top_header_area">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav top_nav">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>317-328-8492</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>info@atcinc.net</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right social_nav">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
<div class="main">
<p>Here i some sample text<br>
  Scroll me<br></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is `mainNavbar()` called?

Comment: Hi @Logan! can you please share a working example? the code snippet you shared doesn't actually do what you said is the current behavior of your code. Because of that, it's hard to quantify `happen more smoothly` without seeing how smooth it is right now.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan mainNavbar() is just called at the end of my JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 $(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() > 20 ){
   $('#top').addClass('slide');
 }
 else{
$('#top').removeClass('slide');
 }
});
```

```css
.top_header_area {
  background: #333333;
}

.top_header_area .top_nav li a {
  font: 400 14px/50px "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.top_header_area .top_nav li a i {
  color: #cc0033;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.top_header_area .top_nav li a:hover,
.top_header_area .top_nav li a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #cc0033;
}

.top_header_area .top_nav li:first-child a {
  padding: 0;
}

.top_header_area .social_nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 12px;
}

.top_header_area .social_nav li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.top_header_area .social_nav li a i {
  line-height: 24px;
}

.top_header_area .social_nav li a:hover,
.top_header_area .social_nav li a:focus {
  background: #cc0033;
  color: #333333;
}
p{
position:absolute;
top:20%;
left:50%;}
.main{
width:100%;
  position:relative;
height:2000px;}

#top.slide{
  transform :translateY(-100%);
  opacity:0;
}
#top{
  transition: all 2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="top" class="top_header_area">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav top_nav">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>317-328-8492</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>info@atcinc.net</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right social_nav">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
<div class="main">
  <p>scroll me</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just write code for them.

Comment: This worked for me, by replacing the function mainNavbar with this I got the effect I was looking for. Thanks Adel!